# How to organize parallelization of the inner loop in the algorithm in python?

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, algorithm, multiprocessing

I started learning programming. How to parallelize the inner loop in the algorithm? Algorithm for summing elements

```
def SumFunc(array):
    y = array
    m = len(array)
    while m != 1:
        i = 0
        j = m - 1
        while i < j:
            y[i] = y[i] + y[j]
            i = i + 1
            j = j - 1
        m = int((m + 1) / 2)
    return y[0]


if __name__ == '__main__':
    numbers = [10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10, 10]
    print(SumFunc(numbers))
```

Comment: The inner loop requires sequential processing. I don't see how you perform multiple operations simultaneously. It may be a better plan to split the initial list and sum each sub-list simultaneously, then merge to new list and rerun.

Comment: Even seasoned programmers struggle with parallelizing code. As a learning path, I'd recommend to first concentrate on sequential processing and code readability.

Answer (score 0):

You can parallelize the inner loop by figuring out it's "iteration size" - how large interval it actually goes through. It does `m // 2` steps and you are only writing into the very first part of the array (from index 0) and reading from the opposite side.

You have **sub-task**: Add to the number at this index number from the opposite side (with same offset)

These sub-tasks can be **grouped** (do it for indexes from some A to B). Groups are independent, so they can be executed in parallel. You should probably create amount of groups ~ equal to number of cores. These groups should evenly cover your interval of indexes.

This would be your sub-task group:

```
for i in range(i_from, i_to):
    array[i] += array[end - i]
```

Your inner loop replacement may look something like this:

```
INTERVAL_SIZE = m // 2
for core in range(N_CORES):
    end = m - 1
    i_from = (core * INTERVAL_SIZE) // N_CORES
    i_to = ((core + 1) * INTERVAL_SIZE) // N_CORES)
    THREAD_POOL[core] = ... # start doing the task with given args

# join later
```

**Example:**

You have array: `[1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6]` with 2 cores.

```
initial m = 6;
Create thread-pool of size 2;
...
INTERVAL_SIZE is 3;
Split it between 2 cores:
   Group 1: Indexes in range(0, 1) => [0]
   Group 2: Indexes in range(1, 3) => [1, 2]
Execute group-tasks in parallel;
Wait until everything is finished (join);
```

There are places for improvement, obviously, but this is a basic idea you could give a try. Personally, I would try a different approach to your problem if it's possible.